# GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener Not Working Properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am sorry to post the whole code to avoid any confusion by others.I implimented GoogleMap sucessfully in my application and i am getting my current location also.My requirement is to get the address of the location whereever the marker is placed.The marker is draggable,but when i shift  or Drag the marker from one place to another i am not getting anything,not even the log.I searched around 2 days for solution.Please try to help me.
Here is my Activity.I am providing whole code including imports to your better understanding.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by noufal on 19/7/16.
 */
public class NewMapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        LocationListener {

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;
        Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        Toolbar toolbar;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinatorLayout;

        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                mCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.signup_coordinator);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
        checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        }
        else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        }

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("Current Latitude:"+location.getLatitude());
        System.out.println("Current Longitude:"+location.getLongitude());

        String mAddress=getCompleteAddressString(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        System.out.println("mAddress:"+mAddress);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(mAddress);

        markerOptions.draggable(true);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mCurrLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();
        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                LatLng position=marker.getPosition();

                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.format("Drag from %f:%f",
                        position.latitude,
                        position.longitude));
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                LatLng position=marker.getPosition();

                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        String.format("Dragging to %f:%f", position.latitude,
                                position.longitude));
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                LatLng position=marker.getPosition();

                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.format("Dragged to %f:%f",
                        position.latitude,
                        position.longitude));
        }
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
        }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // permission was granted. Do the
        // contacts-related task you need to do.
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        } else {

        // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
        Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
        }
        }



        private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
                String strAdd = "";
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
                        if (addresses != null) {
                                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                                String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                                String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                                String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                                }
                                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                                Log.w("MyCurrentctionaddress", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
                        } else {
                                Log.w("MyCurrentloctionaddress", "NoAddress returned!");
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.w("MyCurrentloctionaddress", "Canont get Address!");
                }
                return strAdd;
        }
        // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);

                return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_map_search:
                                findPlace();

                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        public void findPlace() {
                try {
                        Intent intent =
                                new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                        .build(this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        // TODO: Handle the error.
                }
        }
        // A place has been received; use requestCode to track the request.
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
                                Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber() + place.getLatLng().latitude);
                                mMap.clear();
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude);

                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                markerOptions.title(place.getName().toString());

                                markerOptions.draggable(true);
                                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                                mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                                mCurrLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();
                                //move map camera
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));


                        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
                                Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
                                // TODO: Handle the error.
                                Log.e("Tag", status.getStatusMessage());

                        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                                // The user canceled the operation.
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your xml file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add this on your `onMapReady` method:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
```

Comment: This one is not working for me:-(  same thing i did,  but I didn't  get any trigger

Answer (score 2):

Add following line in `onMapReady()`

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
```

Get your marker new position and in `onMarkerDragEnd()` and fetch address from new `LatLng`:

```
// New Marker Position
LatLng position = marker.getPosition();
// Remove Old Marker
mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
// Add New marker position
markerOptions.position(position);
// Add Title on Marker
markerOptions.title(getCompleteAddressString(position.latitude, position.longitude));
// Set Draggable
markerOptions.draggable(true);
// Set Icon of Marker
markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
// Add marker on map
mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
// Show Info window on marker
mCurrLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();
```